# Convert Integer to int in Java

Tags: java, integer

I find a very weird situation when writing Java code:

```
Integer x = myit.next();
if ((int)x % 2 == 0) {
```

In which myit is an Iterator and x is an Integer.
I just want to test whether x is an even number or not. But x % 2 == 0 does not work since eclipse says % not defined on Integer. Then I try to convert x to int by explicitly converting. Again, it warns me that not able to convert in this way.

Any reason why it happened and what is the right way to test if x is even ?

UPDATE:
ANYWAY,I test it that the following code works, which means all of you guys are right.

```
    Integer x = 12;
    boolean y = ( (x % 2) == 0 );
    boolean z = ( (x.intValue() % 2) == 0 );
```

I think the problem I have before may be the context of the code. It is late night, I would update later if I find why would that thing happen.

Comment: Your code works fine when I test using Java 8. Are you possibly using an earlier version of Java>

Comment: @CocoNess It is the first time I met such a dilemma. I use Java 7 in this code. I find other code that use integer.intValue() works but my code does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use :

```
if (x.intValue() % 2 == 0)
```

PS : `if(x % 2==0)` should also work because `integer.intValue()` should be called internally.

Byte code for :`if(x % 2==0)`

```
   11:  invokevirtual   #23; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I   --> line of interest
   14:  iconst_2
   15:  irem
```

Comment: This is not necessary. You can use `%` with `Integer`.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera - yes.. I was checking the byte code to reconfirm `integer.intValue()` was being called.

Answer (score 2):

```
x % 2 == 0 does not work since eclipse says % not defined on Integer
```

This is not true. You can use `%` with `Integer`

take a look at this

```
Integer x = new Integer("6");
  if (x % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.println(x);
  }
```

Out put:

```
6
```

You should read about [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in `Java`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(21);
        myList.add(22);
        myList.add(41);
        myList.add(2);

        Iterator<Integer> itr = myList.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Integer x = itr.next();
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("odd");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
odd
even
odd
even
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(((int)x)%2==0){
```

Note: one more (